# Ruby on Rails, What's the Data Structure of Models Posts, Teams and Players?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I want to create a Site, where

**Teams has many players, and players belongs to team, both teams and players will shows inside posts.**

Example, inside post#show page,

**Title**:

Multi **2 Teams**: USA/UK

and USA/UK **players both inside teams**, so what's the data structure, and Also I want to ask you, I should take these teams as categories, or as tags, if you guys have create any project like this, please share it. or explain it with all code. Thanks